# Very Confusing merges in Git History

Tags: git

how do i fix a situation like this in my git history:

[image]

I want to go back and squash this into a single commit, is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Looks like master~ (the previous black dot; I can't really see the commit hash) is already the commit you're looking for. Why not just reset to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do the squash.

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft HEAD~5
git commit -m "Commit message"
git push -f
```